# SQL How to get all rows with a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hi I want to get all data from customers where the id is in a comma separated list from another table. My current sql query looks like this.

```
SELECT t.trip, t.array, v.* FROM trips t
INNER JOIN customers v ON v.id IN (t.array) 
WHERE t.date='2017-08-21'
ORDER BY t.trip
```

The problem is that it only returns the first row from the customers table, even though there are more than one.

Comment: may be for the given date there is only one row?

Comment: that query equates to writing `on v.id = t.array`. `t.array` doesn't dynamically resolve to a list of value for your `IN` operator.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: Simple. Don't have a comma separated list in another table.

Comment: do you want to `JOIN` all `ids` from `t.array` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your problem it seems like you are trying to `join` `customer` with all the `ids` which are stored as a comma separated list in `t.array`, in such case [FIND_IN_SET](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php) is what you need.

```
SELECT t.trip, t.array, v.* FROM trips t
INNER JOIN customers v ON FIND_IN_SET(v.id,t.array) > 0
WHERE t.date='2017-08-21'
ORDER BY t.trip
```

P.S - its not a good practice to store them as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think in MYSQL you can use FIND_IN_SET

```
CREATE TABLE c_customers (ID int);
CREATE TABLE t_trips (TRIP int, ARRAY VARCHAR(100));

 INSERT INTO c_customers VALUES (1);
 INSERT INTO c_customers VALUES (2);
 INSERT INTO c_customers VALUES (3);

 INSERT INTO t_trips VALUES (1, '1,2');
 INSERT INTO t_trips VALUES (2, '2,3');
 INSERT INTO t_trips VALUES (3, '3,4');


SELECT t.trip, t.array, v.* 
FROM t_trips t 
INNER JOIN c_customers v ON FIND_IN_SET(v.id,t.array) 
WHERE t.trip IN (3);
```

Output:

```
    trip    array   ID
1   3   3,4 3
```